# Apache POI: Setting a date sometimes comes out incorrect in the actual spreadsheet

Tags: apache-poi

This bug has been driving me crazy. I am basically dealing with a lot of data, and part of my code reads in some dates and outputs them into a new spreadsheet. I have noticed a really inconsistent discrepancy where sometimes, only sometimes, 1 second will be added to every single date cell. If I run my program again, it will then be fixed. It makes no sense.

As a test, I event print out some of the date values to the console before outputting the actual file (from the output XSSFWorkbook file) and they're still correct. I'll then open the spreadsheet and they're wrong; super weird.

I've tried multiple solutions like reading the dates as strings and converting them back, changing all deprecated Date values to Calendar, but something breaks after my program, maybe how the data is being read? The only similar case I found about this online was here where that is kind of mentioned:

[POI Java Date to Excel seconds difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378976/poi-java-date-to-excel-seconds-difference)

..but no solution was posted and I wasn't sure how I would use the epoch diff util stuff. My code is too big to share and I don't think the problem is in my code at this point, but I can share some stuff if needed and even try to isolate it to a small sample if that helps.

Any assistance would be great! Thanks!

**SOLVED!**

Amazing. Thanks to Axel Richter' solution, I solved it. I never even thought about milliseconds having an impact; thankfully my data doesn't care about it, so setting them to 0 solved the trick!

Forgive me if I am wrong, but I think the calender.set suggest above doesn't take milliseconds into consideration (it would be year, month, date, hour, minute, second). I didn't see any methods that took in another argument for milliseconds, so I just got around the issue like this:

```
cal.set(y, m, d, h, mi, s);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Thanks again!

Comment: "try to isolate it to a small sample if that helps" This definitely would help. This question lacks a concrete example to be able to reproduce it. Just like your linked unanswered question also lacks one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this question lacks a concrete example, I have a suspicion.

If we are using:

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> "Calendar's getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose
>   calendar fields have been initialized with the current date and time."

So after this we have the current timemillis in the calendar.

If we then do:

```
  calendar.set(2016, 7, 28, 9, 17, 0);
```

we have set year, month, day, hour, minutes and seconds. But we have **not** set milliseconds. So the milliseconds will remain as they were randomly on `Calendar.getInstance()`. And if they were randomly greater than 500 milliseconds we have this one second difference.

So we should do:

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.clear();
  calendar.set(2016, 7, 28, 9, 17, 0);
```

This is: Create a `Calendar` instance with the current datetime, inclusive milliseconds, in it. Then `clear` the calendar. So we can be sure, that milliseconds are undefined. Then `set` desired datetime.

One also could use

```
  GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 7, 28, 9, 17, 0);
```

since this constructor will return a `GregorianCalendar` with exact the given date and time.

Comment: Thanks so much. This helped me solve it. Edited the original question with more info.